# How to make a Django ManyToManyField point to multiple child models

Tags: django, abstract, manytomanyfield

What I would like to do is have something like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

class ChildA(Parent):
    pass

class ChildB(Parent):
    pass

class Test(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(Parent)
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. I get errors:

```
testing.Test.m2m: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Parent', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
testing.Test.m2m: (fields.E307) The field testing.Test.m2m was declared with a lazy reference to 'testing.parent', but app 'testing' doesn't provide model 'parent'.
testing.Test_m2m.parent: (fields.E307) The field testing.Test_m2m.parent was declared with a lazy reference to 'testing.parent', but app 'testing' doesn't provide model 'parent'.
```

This is a simplified test of what I want to do in my main app. I was wondering why this is happening and if there is some way to have a model's ManyToManyField have the ability to inherit multiple types (children) of the model Parent?

EDIT:

I want the Test class to be able to take either ChildA or ChildB in the m2m field. The idea is that there are many types of children. Also, there may be new child models in the future and I would like there to be compatibility. Specifically,

```
class AbstractTrialWFN(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    abstract=True

class CrystalDFT(AbstractTrialWFN):
   # dft fields
   pass

class AbstractQMCRecord(AbstractTrialWFN):
  trial_orbitals = models.OneToOneField(AbstractTrialWFN, verbose_name='Origin of Trial Orbitals' on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class DMCRecord(AbstractQMCRecord):
  # dmc fields
  pass
class VMCRecord(AbstractQMCRecord):
  # vmc fields
  pass
```

The idea is the field trial_orbitals needs to be able to point to either CrystalDFT, DMCRecord or VMCRecord. It also needs to the ability to point to a potential future model that is a child of AbstractTrialWFN.

Comment: Parent class is Abstract class, it means it won't create table in database, it means you cannot do ManyToMany relation with Parent class.

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly your purpose of having Parent class with Test? I think, If you need to create manytomany relationship then you have to create manytomany relationship with i.e. for childa and childb

Comment: Edited my post to be more specific.